# Why can't I access my mariadb after installing homebrew?

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

I just installed homebrew and mariadb via brew.
For some reason, get an error when trying to access the database.
If leave the password as empty, which is normally the default, it gives an error, and if I try to use the rot password it also gives an error.

Here the result I am getting:

```
➜  ~ brew services list
Name    Status  User  Plist
mariadb started refix /Users/refix/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
php     started refix /Users/refix/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~ sudo mysql -uroot
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
➜  ~ sudo mysql -uroot
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
➜  ~
```

How do I access my db?

Comment: The messages are from the system, not from MariaDB server. Apparently, whatever you are entering, is not recognized as your `sudo` password.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `sudo` for database server connection. The prompt is not asking you the password for mysql, but the password for your root account on the operating system.

Besides, `sudo` may ruin the permission of commands, and make you unable to uninstall the package because of lack of privilege perm. (This is exactly what happened on my machine after typing `sudo brew services ...`.)

You'd better run `mysql_secure_installation` after MySQL installation to setup a password, which is recommended.